# Converting to_datetime but keeping original time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to convert string to Datetime- but the conversion adds 5 hours to the original time. How do I convert but keep the time as is?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> t = pd.to_datetime("2016-09-21 08:56:29-05:00", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> t
Timestamp('2016-09-21 13:56:29')
```

Comment: Is it a timezone issue? You could always subtract 5 hours

Comment: remove "`-05:00`" from your string: `t= pd.to_datetime("2016-09-21 08:56:29", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` returns: `Timestamp('2016-09-21 08:56:29')`

Comment: @sacul do you have any idea why this is happening? Just curious

Comment: Also you can use (tz_localize)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html]

Comment: Oh, I see......

Comment: @ChootsMagoots I think that it's interpreting the `-05:00` as a time zone  correction (difference from UTC)

Answer (score 2):

The conversion doesn't add 5 hours to the original time. Pandas just detects that your datetime is timezone-aware and converts it to naive UTC. But it's still the same datetime.

If you want a localized `Timestamp` instance, use [Timestamp.tz_localize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.tz_localize.html#pandas.Timestamp.tz_localize) to make `t` a timezone-aware UTC timestamp, and then use the [Timestamp.tz_convert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html#pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert) method to convert to UTC-0500:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pytz
>>> t = pd.to_datetime("2016-09-21 08:56:29-05:00", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> t
Timestamp('2016-09-21 13:56:29')
>>> t.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(pytz.timezone('America/Chicago'))
Timestamp('2016-09-21 08:56:29-0500', tz='America/Chicago')
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you can remove the "-5:00" from the end of your time string "2016-09-21 08:56:29-05:00"

However, Erik Cederstrand is correct in explaining that pandas is not modifying the time, it's simply displaying it in a different format.

Comment: Are you sure this would be a good idea? It will change the timestamp ...

Comment: @holdenweb I get the impression that this is what OP is asking for. Since they describe pd.to_datetime as "adding 5 hours".

Comment: The question wasn't really detailed about exact requirements, so your guess is as good as mine, I suppose.